# How to copy an array row to a worksheet?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

When I try to copy a row of data from an Array to a worksheet I get

> Error 424

on

```
closedArrayRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

Not the full code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ArrayCopyTEST()
    
    Dim closedArray As Variant ' variable for closed sheet data
    
    'Store the data from the "Closed" worksheet into the array
    closedArray = Worksheets("Closed").UsedRange.Value
    
    closedArray.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"). '<<<<<<<<Error 424 Here
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following . . .

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(closedArray, 1), UBound(closedArray, 2)).Value = closedArray
```